# Errors running a DX9 program

Tags: c++, directx-9

I'm trying to compile the July07 [source code](https://twvideo01.ubm-us.net/o1/vault/GD_Mag_Archives/jul07.zip) from GDMag

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010) i have managed to compile and run different direct x projects but this particular one is not working.

A google search shows that these errors are caused by a missing file namely dinput8.h.  However the SDK only comes with dinput.h and not dinput8.h.

I have tried searching for the [`dinput8.h`](https://github.com/elishacloud/DirectX-Wrappers/blob/master/dinput8/dinput8.h) file on google but I am just finding a wrapper file located which i have inserted in my include folder. However this file has too many dependencies(of which the dependency header files are also missing in the SDK)  thus causing more errors than i can comprehend

I have linked the .lib files in my project correctly so i have no clue how to resolve this.

Regards

The following are the errors:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _c_dfDIJoystick2 error
>
> LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _DirectInput8Create@20 error
>
> LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _D3DXCreateFontA@48 error LNK2001:
>
> unresolved external symbol _IID_IDirectInput8A

Comment: It looks like program wants DirectX8 and you have newer, incompatible version.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no `dinput8.h`. You use `dinput.h` from the legacy DirectX SDK or the Windows SDK and then link with `dinput8.lib`. The legacy Direct SDK (June 2010) does not include support for Direct3D 8 or earlier, but most certainly supports DirectInput 8 (the last one to be released so it was still considered 'current' for DirectX 9.0c).

Given that you are getting an error `_D3DXCreateFontA` related to a missing link statement for the [deprecated] D3DX9 library, you may simply have a problem with your project setup.